# Python program to print out web links containing specific words does not output anything

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I want to print out the web links of news articles containing a specific keyword (say, "Tesla"). So, I search the word "tesla" in Google news home page, and I wrote the following code to search for the articles with the word "Tesla" in it (which should be all the articles, as its searching for the word in a collection of articles that contain the word for sure):

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request('https://news.google.com/search?q=tesla&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aen')

words_to_search = ['tesla']

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml", parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if 'href' in link:
        for word in words_to_search:
            if word in link['href']:
                print(link['href'])
```

But I get no output (or empty output). Why is the code not able to find articles with the specified word? And how do I fix it?

Comment: So `link['href']` is the URL, not the article itself. The URL is likely all in lowercase, so it would probably contain `tesla`, not `Tesla`. You'll need to make another API call to get the article text itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling link[href], you're pulling the URL of the article, which might not contain the word Tesla. You'd want to do something like :

```
resp, content = http.request(link['href'], "GET")
```

to get the actual contents of the page, which would be stored in content.

Also, the sample search link you have in the example is searching for the word 'insurance' in Google News, so if that's the link you're really using, you might not be pulling articles with Tesla in them.